# What changes `self` in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, oop, self

I got completely lost about the `self` keyword. How does it change when we enter into a module, class, method, block, or everything else? Can anyone give me a summary?

Here I'm asking how does self change along execution instead of what self means.

Comment: I know what self is, but I want a summary of how self changes as when enter into module, class, method, block, or everything else.

Comment: Title edited to better reflect the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike JavaScript where `this` might refer to any number of things, in Ruby `self` always refers to the *execution context* of the current method.

Within a `class` method, `self` will refer to the class itself:

```
class FooClass
  def self.bar
    self # => FooClass
  end
end
```

Within a `class` instance method, `self` will refer to the instance:

```
class FooClass
  def bar
    self # => This instance (FooClass#nnnn)
  end
end
```

Within a `module` method, `self` may refer to the module:

```
module FooModule
  def self.bar
    self # => FooModule
  end
end
```

When a module method is mixed in via `include` it will refer to an instance:

```
module FooModule
  def bar
    self # => (Depends on included context)
  end
end

class BarClass
  include FooModule

  def foo
    bar # => This instance (BarClass#nnnn)
  end
end
```

The only tricky part is modules, and they're only tricky because other things can include them. The way to remember it best is `self` generally refers to the thing on the *left-hand* side of the dot. That is `my_object.foo` means `self` is `my_object` in the immediate context of that method.

There are ways of re-defining `self` within the context of a block by using `instance_eval` and `class_eval` type operations, or `class << self` declarations to manipulate the *eigenclass*.

Answer (score 3):

`self` always refers to the current object.

```
class A
  p self # => A

  def foo
    p self # => instance of A
  end
end

module M
  p self # => M
end

A.new.foo
```

Comment: That is just a rephrasing, not an explanation.

Comment: Maybe add `instance_eval` and friends as other ways to change `self`